# Including files/header in SublimeClang

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 and using SublimeText 3. For my master-thesis i will work with the logging-API Pantheios, so i want to include it into SublimeClang.
Everyhting works fine, but Pantheios won't be integrated. Here are my user settings from SublimeClang:

```
{
"enabled": true,
"dont_prepend_clang_includes": true,
"show_output_panel": true,
"hide_output_when_empty": true,
"show_status": true,
"show_visual_error_marks": true,
"auto_complete": true,
"tab_completion": true,
"additional_language_options": 
{
  "c++" : ["-std=c++11"]
},
"options":
[
    "-I/usr/include/c++/4.6",
    "-I${folder:${project_path:rmf.sublime-project}}/source/**",
]
}
```

And the error:

```
/media/tobias/Data/Dropbox/Masterarbeit/RateMeasurementFramework/source/measurementMethods/../pantheios/pantheiosHeader.h:5,10 - Fatal - 'pantheios/pantheios.hpp' file not found
Did you configure the include path used by clang properly?
See http://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang for more details on how to configure SublimeClang.
```

The path for the pantheios.hpp is

```
/media/tobias/Data/Dropbox/Masterarbeit/RateMeasurementFramework/source/pantheios/pantheios.hpp
```

Last intereseting file maybe is the pantheios header itself:

```
/* FILE: pantheiosHeader.h */
#ifndef _pantheiosHeader_
#define _pantheiosHeader_

#include <pantheios/pantheios.hpp>
#include <pantheios/inserters/integer.hpp>
#include <pantheios/inserters/real.hpp>
#include <pantheios/backends/bec.file.h>
#include <pantheios/backends/bec.fprintf.h>

extern int pantheois_logLevel;  // Reference to "rmf.cpp" to control the loglevel

#endif /* PANTHEIOSFRONTEND_H_ */
```